# Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following code and error. So please give me some suggestion how to resolve this?

```
include('config/setup.php');
$query="select * from tbluser";
$fetch=mysqli_query($connect,$query) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch);

echo $row['join_date']."</br>";
echo $date=strtotime($row['join_date'])."</br>";
echo $a=date('d-M-Y',$date)
```

> 2014-05-04
>
> 1399154400
>
> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\flipkart\index.php on line 12
>       04-May-2014

Comment: Passing `timestamp</br>` to `date()` probably doesn't work like you think. Why would you echo setting a variable like that

Comment: @Barmar   echo $a=date('d-M-Y',$date)."</br>"; this is line 12

Comment: And that line is totally hinky, what are you expecting to get from that ?

Comment: @adeneo this tag does not effect because i have checked it without tag.......

Comment: @adeneo Actually i need yyyy-mm-dd this date format in 21-may-2014 this format so that's why i did it

Comment: What tag? The question is, when you're setting a variable, as in `$date  = strtotime(string)`, what are you expecting to echo, and why would you even echo that directly. Also, when concantenating in the (not valid) HTML `</br>` what are you expecting, as noted you now have the string `1399154400</br>`, and why would that be valid as a date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do:

```
echo $date=strtotime($row['join_date'])."</br>";
```

You're setting `$date` to the string `"1399154400</br>"`. `date()` expects its second argument to be a number, and this isn't a number because it ends with `</br>`.

Change it to:

```
$date=strtotime($row['join_date']);
echo $date . "<br/>";
```

or:

```
echo $date=strtotime($row['join_date']), "<br/>";
```

This sends `<br/>` as a separate argument to `echo`, rather than concatenating it when doing the assignment.

BTW, the correct tag for line breaks is `<br/>`, not `</br>`

Answer (score 0):

You are actually Passing the time with the `<br />` tag... 
So `$date` is not numeric anymore.
Place it directly inside the `date()` function...

```
include('config/setup.php');
$query="select * from tbluser";
$fetch=mysqli_query($connect,$query) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch);

echo $row['join_date']."<br />";
echo strtotime($row['join_date'])."<br />";
echo date('d-M-Y', strtotime($row['join_date']));
```

Comment: this answer fails to address the setting of the variable '$a'